# Chronoforms 6 data mask options

Tags: mask, sanitization, chronoforms

On Chronoforms6 there is an option to provide data masking for text fields.
I used the following entry in the Entry parameters:

data-inputmask='mask' : '*{1,30}'

What I also need is to allow spaces and - characters.
The above only allows alphanumerics.

Any hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ChronoForms uses Robin Herbots InputMask library - please see the documentation on GitHub [here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask). A Regexp mask or a custom format might solve your problem.